# excel VBA 1004 error when copying multiple tabs into one tab from a folder

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting a 1004 error when I try and combine workbook pages into one master document. The code works correctly on my device, but when I attempt to run the code on my friends device it throw a 1004 error. I believe he is on excel 2013, I am on excel 2016. Is there any way to convert my code into something that can be used on both devices?

```
Sub CombineSheets()
Dim sPath As String
Dim sFname As String
Dim wBk As Workbook
Dim wSht As Variant

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
sPath = InputBox("Enter a full path to workbooks")
ChDir sPath
sFname = InputBox("Enter a filename pattern")
sFname = Dir(sPath & "\" & sFname & ".xl*", vbNormal)
wSht = InputBox("Enter a worksheet name to copy")
Do Until sFname = ""
    Set wBk = Workbooks.Open(sFname)
    Windows(sFname).Activate
    Sheets(wSht).Copy Before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    wBk.Close False
    sFname = Dir()
Loop
ActiveWorkbook.Save
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This works correctly when I run it, prompts for the folder location, asks which files it should copy from (usually *), and then copies from specifically the worksheet name entered.

Realistically all I need is code that can extract one worksheet from several hundred excel files and combine them into one master document. being able to pick and choose which worksheets would just be a bonus.

Thank you!

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Comment: Don't `Activate` the window, don't use unqualified `Sheets` collection implicitly referring to the active workbook. Use the `Worksheets` collection instead of the `Sheets` collection if you intend to work with `Worksheet` objects only. Use your `wBk` workbook object reference instead. `wkb.Worksheets(wSht).Copy Before:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)`. Call `ThisWorkbook.Save` instead of relying on it being implicitly re-activated after closing `wBk`.

Comment: Also, your code assumes user input is valid, and doesn't validate anything. Perhaps start with input validation?

Comment: are the files on network drive. if so, are they mapped on both your pc's with the same drive letter, like "F:". Perhaps his mapping is not done he sees the path \\sa0036\blabla\foobar whereas you see the same path like "F:\foobar"

Comment: The line that throws the error is: 
     Sheets(wSht).Copy Before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
sorry I'm very new here (signed up today)

Comment: Please [edit] your question so that it includes all the relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

Like Mat's Mug said, you should really validate you inputs.

Did your co-worker add a "\" at the end of the path?  Does the Path even exist?

Test to make sure that the sheet exists in the file that you are copying from, with something like this:

```
Function SheetExists(Name As String, Optional Workbook As Excel.Workbook = Nothing) As Boolean
If Workbook Is Nothing Then Set Workbook = ThisWorkbook.Application.ActiveWorkbook
On Error Resume Next
    If Workbook.Worksheets(Name).Name <> vbNullString Then
    End If
    If Err.Number = 0 Then SheetExists = True
On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Here is your code with the noted changes:

```
Sub CombineSheets()
Dim sPath As String
Dim sFname As String
Dim wBk As Workbook
Dim sSht As String

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
sPath = InputBox("Enter a full path to workbooks")
'Use the FolderPicker to verify the path
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    If .Show Then sPath = .SelectedItems(1)
End With
'ChDir sPath
sFname = InputBox("Enter a filename pattern")
sFname = Dir(sPath & "\" & sFname & ".xl*", vbNormal)
sSht = InputBox("Enter a worksheet name to copy")
Do Until sFname = ""
    Set wBk = Workbooks.Open(sFname)
    'Windows(sFname).Activate
    If SheetExists(sSht, wBk) Then
        wBk.Sheets(sSht).Copy Before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    End If
    wBk.Close False
    sFname = Dir()
Loop
'ActiveWorkbook.Save
ThisWorkbook.Save
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The bigger question is, are the Sheets the same size?  Old `.xls` files only have 65536 rows, where 2007+ .xlsx files go up to 1048576 rows.

You can't mix the two different worksheets.  In that case, you need to copy all of the cells from one sheet to the other.

```
wBk.Sheets(sSht).Cells.Copy
ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add Before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1) 
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Paste
```